# How to bind a luafunction to keypress in vim

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to execute a imported function on a button click, but I get an error that its undefined.

```lua
local LazyComp = require('plugins/LazyComp/LazyComp')
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<Tab>', "LazyComp.getFile()<cr>", {expr = true, noremap = true})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a vim script expression in that mapping. Not a Lua function call. There's no way to get that local variable called from nvim through a string.

I'm no expert in nvim's Lua API but 1 minute of websearch gave me this solution:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<TAB>', "<cmd>lua require('plugins/LazyComp/LazyComp').getFile()<CR>")
```

Alternatively you need to make your module available globally.

```
_G.LazyComp = require('plugins/LazyComp/LazyComp')
```

Then you should be able to access the global environemt through `v:lua`

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<TAB>', "v:lua.LazyComp.getFile()<CR>")
```

Both untested.

Answer (score 5):

Modern way for keymaps is to use `vim.keymap.set`:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', 'lhs', function() print("A lua func") end, {noremap = true})
```

Comment: I must also set the option to `{ expr = true }` for it to work.

Comment: If you change `{ expr = true }` for `{ noremap = true }` does it work for you @FanchenBao ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Without `{ expr = true }`, the function I passed to rhs is not recognized. I am using NVIM v0.9.5.

Comment: Can you post your whole keymap, cause it works for me in Nvim 0.9 and nvim 0.10, I suspect it is the keymap you are performing.

Comment: I was following the Expression Mapping guide from [the documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.keymap.set()). And [here is my custom keymaps](https://github.com/FanchenBao/kickstart-modular.nvim/blob/fanchen.bao.setup/lua/custom/config.lua).

Comment: The file you linked to does not have any keymaps. Instead of saying over and over again it does not work, post exactly what is not working for you, cause works for others, or better yet ask a question with your specific problem.

Comment: Sorry, I recently restructured my neovim config, and the link indeed no longer works. Here is the [new link to my keympas](https://github.com/FanchenBao/kickstart-modular.nvim/blob/fanchen.bao.setup/lua/custom/keymaps.lua).